# Marble on a rotating inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

A marble moves on a smooth plane which is inclined at an angle θ to the horizontal.
The whole plane rotates at constant angular speed ω about a vertical axis through a point
O fixed in the plane. Coordinates (ξ, η) are defined with respect to axes fixed in the plane:
Oξ horizontal and Oη up the line of greatest slope in the plane. Ensuring that you account
for the normal reaction force, find $\xi'', \eta''$.

By considering the marble’s kinetic energy as measured on the plane in the rotating frame,
or otherwise, find a constant of the motion.

### [You may assume that the marble never leaves the plane.]

For the last part, am I to assume that the quantity $T=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is conserved? This gives me $\frac{\omega^2}{2}(\xi^2+\eta^2\cos^2(\theta))-g\sin(\theta) \eta$ is constant.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Comment: No the question does not intend that you should assume that kinetic energy is conserved - because that would immediately answer the question of finding a constant of the motion. The question is giving you a clue as to how to find a constant of the motion, by *considering KE as measured in the rotating (accelerating) frame of reference*.